# no sound on lubuntu, pulseaudio and pavucontrol seem operational

Tags: pulseaudio

Hi I have an acer aspire switch 10e (which is a notebook) and lubuntu 21.04 is running on it.
I have no sound even though my hard ware seems to be recognised:

These are screenshots from pulseaudio gui settings.

Configuration:
[image]
Ouput devices:
[image]
Playing:
[image]

The sound playing in the web browser is being processed and the level goes up and down, but I get no sound on either headset or speakers.

Processor Intel Atom Z3735F

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer but this iso is still downloadable on lubuntu.net and is supported untill 2023 if i'm correct.

Comment: Firstly the web site you mention is neither a Lubuntu, Ubuntu or Canonical web site; so I have no idea what it says & won't check it either (if you were using ublock.origin you'd have been warned it wasn't a *legit* site).  If you don't know how to pick *legit* sites and not *fan* or *fake* sites; don't use search engines & go to ubuntu.com & you'll go to official web sites (eg. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will take you to the Ubuntu *flavor* sites). Parts of the system are supported; Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOL (Lubuntu is LXQt only now; oldest supported is Lubuntu 20.04 LTS).

Comment: If you scan https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ you'll note only Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud & Ubuntu Base are mentioned; as *flavors* were already EOL before the release of 18.04.6; so any Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS media you claim to have installed on is *fake* and was not created by the Lubuntu team, Ubuntu only created what I already mentioned was supported. See my first comment for the team's last 18.04 mention (https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/)

Comment: Yes I know the lubuntu.net looks weird; I did not get the iso from there actually.
I wonder why it comes in top of the searches and the official is hard to find.
Anyway I'm giving up with it now I'm installing Parrot sec so that even with no sound I'd have toys...

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: @guiverc I have found the solution for the sound and will post it as an answer but I need to know how to set quirks on Lubuntu, there is no loader folder in /boot.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by *quirks*, and Lubuntu doesn't touch /boot (xcept for the addition of a grub theme (ie. it's identical for Ubuntu or and other *flavor* of Ubuntu; which can vary on release, as Ubuntu now keeps all architectures booting the same for a given release)

Comment: For as much as I understood what a quirk it, it's a kernel option used to remap drivers functions.
I found the solution here:https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter
My notebook is not well handled by linux and I have to tweak a lot, since lid close is not recognized by any other than chromeos I switched to that and now am trying to set these quirks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211485), and if you go and read it you will find that we need to [add snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640.quirk=0x502f30 to the kernel command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter).